# Using imports instead of require's in ExpressJS with Webpack and Babel

Tags: express, webpack, babeljs

I have been following [this set of tutorials](https://medium.com/@TeeFouad/create-a-react-application-from-scratch-part-1-introduction-b2e66dfb3aae), in which the writer uses `import` instead of `require`. Unfortunately, when I do this it doesn't work. I am using `babel-preset-env` instead of the `stage-0` and `babel-preset-es2015` presets used in the tutorial. I am also using yarn instead of npm.

`babel-node ...`, works fine, however, when I use `node ...` I get errors saying `unexpected token import`. I can't use `babel-node` in production, so I am trying to solve this issue now.

What is the correct way to do this? It is too much code to post here so here is a link to the git repo: https://github.com/mjhough/react-express-sample

Comment: Essentially You need to compile your ES2015 modules to something Node understands (commonjs). You can also try experimenting with ES2015 module support with the latest Node version v10 as shown [here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html)

Comment: @FranciscoMateo So `babel-preset-env` doesn't do that? Is there a babel preset that introduces import/export functionality?